# Access query not using index

Tags: database, ms-access, indexing, ado

I have a table in Access with 1 field called HostName, it is a text field, with 100 char max.  I use it to store DNS host names.  The field is setup as the primary key.  If I do the following query it returns the expected results, but takes about 8 seconds to complete on a table with 1 million records:

SELECT TOP 1 HostsRev.HostName
FROM HostsRev
WHERE (((HostsRev.HostName)>="test"))
ORDER BY HostsRev.HostName;

If I remove the "ORDER BY" part, it returns in less than 1 second, but doesn't always return what I would expect -- not the first record that is >= to "test".

I am doing the query via ADO from a C++ app, but I've tested in Access also, by creating a query, and get the same results.

What I need is to quickly find the first record, if any, that starts with a given string.  I also tried using LIKE query but that had the same results.  I need to do this because if I search on images.google.com, I need to know if the list contains google.com but not images.google.com (I actually store the host names in reverse string order to make this work correctly, and reverse the strings before doing the lookup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the TOP command on it's own does not apply sorting to the data, so without the ORDER BY it will return in a different order and thus give different results, you could try the following instead:

```
SELECT Min(HostName) FROM HostsRev WHERE HostName >= "test"
```

Not sure if this will give any better performance though but worth a go : )

Comment: This was the problem, I just ended up solving it a bit differently.  Since my hostnames use a known format, I added something like WHERE HostName >= "test" AND HostName <= ".test", which got the initial filtering down to just a few records and then the select top 1 could still be fast.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can do this from C++, not being a C++ programmer, but ADO supports a property .index to allow you to set the index you wish to use and a .seek method to search on that index. here is some code in VB for what it is worth.

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open ConnectionString

rs.Open "mytable", conn
rs.Index = "primarykey"
rs.Seek "test", adSeekAfterEQ
If rs.EOF Then ' record not found
```